# HPE Application Automation Tools Plugin Execute performance test using Performance Center

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I am getting the following error when trying to create a Job using the HPE Application Automation Tools Plugin. Even if I try to save the Job without entering anything I get this error. Can anyone help?

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Refusing to marshal com.microfocus.adm.performancecenter.plugins.common.pcEntities.TimeslotDuration for security reasons; see https://jenkins.io/redirect/class-filter/
    at hudson.util.XStream2$BlacklistedTypesConverter.marshal(XStream2.java:543)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:265)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:252)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize com.hpe.application.automation.tools.model.PcModel#timeslotDuration for class com.hpe.application.automation.tools.model.PcModel
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:256)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:224)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:138)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:209)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:150)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:265)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:252)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize com.hpe.application.automation.tools.run.PcBuilder#pcModel for class com.hpe.application.automation.tools.run.PcBuilder
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:256)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:224)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:138)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:209)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:150)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:64)
    at hudson.util.DescribableList$ConverterImpl.marshal(DescribableList.java:269)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:265)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:252)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.Project#builders for class hudson.model.FreeStyleProject
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:256)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:224)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:138)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:209)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:150)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1026)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1015)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:988)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:193)
Caused: java.io.IOException
```